# Typesetting columnar or tabular data

Tags: columns

How can I write 2 simple columns with data?

For example like this:

```
 a      kjh
 f      ghjjjk
 f      gtrgthgthtyhth
```

I tried /twocolumns but I didnt get this result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For basic representation of data, use `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ c c }
  a & kjh            \\
  f & ghjjjk         \\
  f & gtrgthgthtyhth
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: But I like teh second column to be intended, I mean in a straight line

Comment: @JohnDow: You're probably talking about the column specification being `c`entred. You can try with `l`eft or `r`ight-aligned. That is, `\begin{tabular}{ l l }` or `\begin{tabular}{ c r }`.